# How to find the secret path in the Jungle Temple in Lara Croft Relic Run?

Tags: lara-croft-relic-run

There is this mobile video game called Lara Croft Relic Run developed by Square Enix that has three stages namely:

- **Jungle Temple**
  The Jungle Temple is technically a jungle with plants and booby traps that Lara should overcome and defeat the boss which happens to be a giant Tyrannosaurus. This is the level whose secret path I have failed to beat.
- **The Desert Ruins**
  The Desert Ruins is the level that gets unlocked when you beat the level above. I did manage to find the secret path for this and unlocked it in the achievements section.
- **The Mountain Pass** This is the final level of the video game and is considered to be complete after you beat a demon called Oni. I do not know if this level has a secret path but I would love to unlock it if exists.

Each level above contains 40 sub levels and the level that let's you beat the boss is usually three or two milestones from the final level. So how do I play this to unlock the secet path in the Jungle Temple?